# How to cancel a case when interactive textbox selects cancel

Tags: excel, vba

So I am writing a case function that when an event (7 - Engaged) occurs an interactive textbox pops up asking the user to confirm this action. If they select OK the data is moved to another spreadsheet.

That all works dandy but probably needs revising to tidy it.

Anyways, the issue arises when the user selects cancel.
Instead of just leaving the function the line of data is deleted.

I believe this issue is the last couple lines deletes anything that is 7-engaged, but I haven't written a piece of code to bring the value down to 6 if the user cancels out.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
    ' Maybe disable events whilst this code runs (and re-enable before exit)
    ' to prevent recursion.

```
' The three range rows are to move sepearate sections of data from pipeline into isolated blocks in tank.

 If Source.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub ' 9 = I
 If Source.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' Check this first before making comparison on next line
 If Source.Value <> "7 - engaged" Then Exit Sub

If MsgBox("Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tank") 'Produces an interactive dialoge box prompting the user to confirm they wish ti import to tank
    'The code only fires if they confirm - if not, the line will remain in Pipeline.
        Dim rowToPasteTo As Long
        rowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "D" & rowToPasteTo).Value = Sh.Range("A" & Source.Row & ":" & "M" & Source.Row).Value
        .Range("G" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "H" & rowToPasteTo).Value = Sh.Range("E" & Source.Row & ":" & "F" & Source.Row).Value
        .Range("S" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "U" & rowToPasteTo).Value = Sh.Range("K" & Source.Row & ":" & "M" & Source.Row).Value



    End With

 End If

If Source.Column = 9 And Source.Value = "7 - engaged" Then
Source.EntireRow.Delete

' The above line deleted the row from pipeline once it has been imported in Tank

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Would that not still delete the line regardless if accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I have now added this piece of code which negates the problem.

```
 If MsgBox("Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
Source.Value = "6 - KYC in progress" ' If cancel is selected the value goes back to Case 6 and the line is kept.


End If
```